# i go back to first page everytime i change my pagination leghth

Tags: php, laravel

im working on a dynamic paginator that allows user to determine number of member that show per page
.but the problem is, whenever i change the paginator lenght, it goes back to page 1

ex : im on page 3 and show 10 members per page( which is showing member 21-30 ), when i change to show 30 members per page it goes back to first page and show member 1 - 30, but i want it to stay to pages 3 and show member 30-60

```
public function list(Request $request)
{
    $items = $request->items ?? 10;
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
    $members = Member::paginate($items)->withQueryString();
    return view('members', [
        'members' => $members,
        'page_title' => 'Member List',
        'items' => $items
    ]);
}
```

heres my member list controller
{{ $members->appends('items')->links() }}

```
        <form>
            <select id="pagination">
                <option value="10" @if($items == 10) selected @endif >10</option>
                <option value="30" @if($items == 30) selected @endif >30</option>
                <option value="50" @if($items == 50) selected @endif >50</option>
                <option value="100" @if($items == 100) selected @endif >100</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('pagination').onchange = function() { 
        window.location = "{!! $members->url(1)!!}&items=" + this.value; 
    }; 
</script>
```

this is my pagination lenght limit

Comment: you have to count all the items than call paginator method

Comment: Store your current page number somewhere (hidden field) and add that to your URL. Make sure there are enough items to show first. IMHO what you're after is not very user-friendly, if you're showing items 21-30 and switch to 30 items per page _and_ stay on page 3 you'd miss some entries. (fyi, page3 with 30 items per page would show items 61-90)